# docker-compose how to define container scoped network like in docker run?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Running 2 containers where `mycontainer2` must use the same network stack of `mycontainer1`. As if the two containers were running in the same machine. Here how I try to do by using `docker run` with [--network container:xxx](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings)

```
$ docker run -it --rm --name mycontainer1 -p 6666:7777 myregistry/my-container1:latest

$ docker run -it --rm --network container:mycontainer1 --name mycontainer2 myregistry/my-container2:latest
```

I tried to replicate this behavior using `docker-compose` instead. But the [networks: definition](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks) of `docker-compose.yaml` doesn't indicate something equivalent to the `--network container:xxx` option of `docker run`. Is it possible in `docker-compose` to configure two containers to use the same network stack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [`network_mode:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode) setting.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  mycontainer1:
    image: myregistry/my-container1:latest
    ports: ['6666:7777']
  mycontainer2:
    image: myregistry/my-container2:latest
    network_mode: service:mycontainer1     # <---
```

Since Compose will generally pick its own container names, this `service:name` form uses the container matching the named Compose service.  (If you override `container_name:` then you can also use `container:mycontainer1` the same way you did with `docker run`.)

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much. BTW what is the difference between `ports: ['6666:7777']` and `ports: <newline> - '6666:7777'`

Comment: Oh please ignore. This is just a different way of writing items in a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an external network and use it inside docker-compose YAML manifest might help. Here is how you do it.

```
version: '3.7'
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: an-external-network
services:
  my-container1:
   ...
  my-container2:
   ...
```

> Note: use `docker network create` command to create `an-external-network` before running `docker-compose up` command.

Comment: Sorry this is not the same. Here the two containers share the same network space, but each has a different IP address. What I was looking for was the same network stack, 1 single IP, ie the two services can refer to each other via localhost, as if they were in the same machine.